# State interface properties in TypeScript + React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am rewriting the existing code in JavaScript to TypeScript. However, I am a little bit newbie in React Native. My problem is:

I have a custom `Component` with custom `State` interface. I want to resolve the errors I am getting right now inside the component itself by customizing the `State` interface. Here is the code I have for the interface:

```
interface MeterReadingStaticState {
  process: any,
  selected: {
    value: any,
    isAccepted: boolean,
    type: any,
  },
  isLoaded: boolean,
}
```

and this is a content of my `Component`:

```
export default class MeterReadingStatic extends Component<
    MeterReadingStaticProps, MeterReadingStaticState> {
  state: MeterReadingStaticState = {
    selected: {
    value: '',
    isAccepted: false,
    type: '',
  },
    process: [],
    isLoaded: false
  };

onAcceptPress = () => {
    const updatedProcess = this._updateObj('isAccepted', true);
    this.setState({ process: updatedProcess });
  };

_updateObj = (prop: MeterReadingStaticProps, value: any) => {
    const { process, selected } = this.state;
    const target = process.filter(
      item => item.name === selected.name && item.type === selected.type
    )[0];
    target[prop] = value;

    const updatedProcess = process.map(
      item =>
        item.name === target.name && item.type === target.type ? target : item
    );

    return updatedProcess;
  };
```

As it can be seen from the code above, I want to access specific parameters of state properties. However, I am getting a bunch of errors when I am trying to do so. I also get some errors when I try to initialize my `State` and when I try to `_updateObj` in `onAcceptPress` function.

I haven't found any sources on such specific case in defining an interface of a `State`. Any solutions on that?

Comment: What specific errors are you getting ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Property 'type' does not exist on type 'MeterReadingStaticState'.

Answer (score 0):

First, can I ask if your MeterReadingStaticState is in the same file of your class?

Second, can you see your package.json file and make sure that you have your typescript installed properly?

Let me know about it because it might help to solve the problem

Comment: Yes, it is in the same class. And yes, typescript is installed and workes well. I can see it from other classes.

Comment: Okay, can you give the screenshot of typescript error that you encountered?